# Trouble downloading Maven Repositories when syncing sbt project in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, repository

When trying to sync an `sbt` file through `IntelliJ` with Dependencies

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"`

"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
```

it failed because

> C:\Users\Owner.ivy2\local\org.apache.parquet\parquet-column\1.8.1\ivys\ivy.xml
>   was not found.

I do not have this file. How should I acquire files that are missing when downloading from remote repositories (like `Maven` repositories)?
What should I do?

Comment: Where is the error shown? In the sbt output? Is this the only error?

Comment: In the sbt, after typing "compile", I get this error. It is not the only error.